# Converting int[] to String in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, std

I have a string defined as `std::string header = "00110033";`
now I need the string to hold the byte values of the digits as if its constructed like this

```
char data_bytes[] = { 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 3};
std::string header = new std::string(data_bytes, 8).c_str());
```

I converted the initial string to `int` array using `atoi`. Now i'm not sure how to make the string out of it. Let me know if there is any better approach.

Comment: I am unable to understand your question.

Comment: syntax of 2nd line isn't correct. Also, what's the intention of the `new` here?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What are you going to do if the array contains a value that is not between 0 and 9?

Comment: It's inefficient (due to copying) and a memory leak (due to `new` without storing the pointer for a corresponding `delete`) to say `std::string header = (new std::string(data_bytes, 8))->c_str();` (or whatever it is you meant). You can just say `std::string header(data_bytes, 8);` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could write a little function

```
string int_array_to_string(int int_array[], int size_of_array) {
  string returnstring = "";
  for (int temp = 0; temp < size_of_array; temp++)
    returnstring += itoa(int_array[temp]);
  return returnstring;
}
```

<sup>untested!</sup>

a slightly different approach

```
string int_array_to_string(int int_array[], int size_of_array) {
  ostringstream oss("");
  for (int temp = 0; temp < size_of_array; temp++)
    oss << int_array[temp];
  return oss.str();
}
```

Comment: @ultifinitus atoi converts string to int, while you need to convert int to string. You need to use itoa, which is not standard function, so probably best solution is to convert int to character by adding '0' (see my solution). You also can use lexical cast: `boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(int_array[temp]);`

Comment: Use `std::stringstream` instead, it's safer.

Comment: Oh good heavens, I'll revamp it, it was a 5 second function geez! =)

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
  char data_bytes[] = { '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '3', '3', '\0'};
  std::string header(data_bytes, 8);
```

Or maybe, you want to do this:

```
  std::stringstream s;
  s << data_bytes;
  std::string header = s.str();
```

Demo at ideone : http://ideone.com/RzrYY

---

EDIT:

Last `\0` in data_bytes is necessary. Also see this interesting output here: http://ideone.com/aYtlL

PS: I didn't know this before, thanks to **Ashot** I came to know this difference by experimenting!

Comment: You can't store ints in a char array

Comment: @Nawaz -1 data_bytes is not ending with '\0' so you can't print it. + In both cases your  string will not be equal to string("00110033");

Comment: You won't get the results you expect

Comment: @Ashot: I saw that, and fixed it as well. @Nicklamort: The problem is fixed. However, it was nothing to do with "storing ints ina char".

Comment: @Nawaz remove last '\0' in data_bytes. Your string is ending with double '\0' now :) See this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711449/what-does-the-0-symbol-mean-in-a-c-string.

Comment: @Ashot: I think that is correct. See this (sizeof vs. strlen): http://ideone.com/aYtlL

Comment: @Eugen Constantin Dinca  you are right, thet's why I undo my downvote, but if last '\0' is not necessary, why write it?

Comment: @Ashot: I updated the link in my previous comment. Please see it again : http://ideone.com/aYtlL

Comment: @Nawaz,  I can't re vote for this answer until you don't edit your question

Comment: Perhaps you should provide an answer matching the question instead of interpreting the question to match your answer.

Comment: @Ashot: I not only edited, but also mentioned the difference. Learned something new today. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
 char data_bytes[] = { 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 3};
  std::string str;
 for(int i =0;i<sizeof(data_bytes);++i)
      str.push_back('0'+data_bytes[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using a "fairly normal" system where the numeric values of `'0'` to `'9'` are consecutive, you can just iterate over each element and subtract `'0'`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < header.size(); ++i)
{
    header[i] -= '0';
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be adding instead of substracting?

Comment: @Eugen Constantin Dinca The OP has a string like "00111" and wants it to be translated to one with those actual byte values, for example "00111" -> "\000\000\001\001\001". Thus you subtract.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
std::string header( data_bytes, data_bytes + sizeof( data_bytes ) );
std::transform( header.begin(), header.end(), header.begin(), 
     std::bind1st( std::plus< char >(), '0' ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

If **integ[]** is the integer array, and **s** is the final string we wish to obtain,

```
string s="";

for(auto i=0;i<integ.size()-1; ++i)
    s += to_string(ans[i]); 

cout<<s<<endl;
```