# c++ int[] to string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, int

I have a long array of ints that need to be converted to string. The array is about 1000 - 10000 ints long and value of all of those ints is between 0-9. Is there any fast and effective STANDARD way to convert whole int array to string? It really has to be done only using standard libraries. Thanks.

Comment: Could you give an example of a string that you'd like to get from an array of `{1,2,3}`?

Comment: Is a for loop not fast enough? Even not with preallocating the string?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223066/converting-int-to-string-in-c

Comment: I think that could help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223066/converting-int-to-string-in-c

Cheers

Marcel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::string` or C `string`?

Anyway for one character, the conversion is: `char c = array[i]+'0';`

Extended that over entire array and you are done.

Comment: thanks, i didnt think that it will be that simple. It's very fast too, whole conversion (300 ints) ends in less than 1 sec.

Answer (score 7):

Old C++:

```
std::string s; s.reserve(arr_len);
std::transform(arr, arr+arr_len, std::back_inserter(s),
               std::bind1st(std::plus<int>(), '0'));
```

C++11:

```
 std::transform(arr, arr+arr_len, std::back_inserter(s),
               [](int c){return c+'0';});
```

Not that 1+'0' is not necessarily '1', but in practice you can safely assume so.

Comment: The standard guarantees that the ten decimal digits are in sequential ascending order, so `1 + '0'` is guaranteed to be `'1'`.  (This is about the only guarantee it gives concerning encoding---in particular `1 + 'a'` is not guaranteed to be `'b'`.  Or even a letter.)

Comment: thanks, but these functions aren't included in standard libraries, are they?

Comment: Yes, they are.  You have to include `<algorithm>` and `<functional>` to take use of them.

Answer (score 1):

It depends largely on the semantics of those `int`s.  If they're
descrete values (say the results of throwing 1000&ndahs;10000 ten sided
dice), then something like:

```
std::ostream&
operator<<( std::ostream& dest, std::vector<int> const& source )
{
    dest << '[';
    for ( std::vector<int>::const_iterator current = source.begin();
            current != source.end();
            ++ current ) {
        if ( current != source.begin() ) {
            dest << ", ";
        }
        dest << *current;
    }
    dest << ']';
    return dest;
}
```

might do the trick; more likely, you'd want to pick up `dest.width()`,
and set it before the output of each int (or treat it as the total
width, and work out how much padding you need per `int`, and set that
before outputting each int), and you also might want to insert line
breaks.

If, on the other hand, your vector is a single number in base 10, with
one digit per `int` (in which case, I'd recommend using `char`, rather
than int), you want something like:

```
std::ostream&
operator<<( std::ostream& dest, std::vector<int> const& source )
{
    std::vector<int>::const_reverse_iterator current 
        = std::find_if( source.rbegin(), source.rend(),
                        boost::bind( std::not_equal_to<int>(), _1, 0 ) );
    if ( current == source.rend() ) {
        dest << '0';
    } else {
        while ( current != source.rend() ) {
            dest << *current + '0';
            ++ current;
        }
    }
    return dest;
}
```

(This is for a little endian representation; for bigendian, replace the
reverse iterators with normal iterators.)

Again, you'll probably want to handle `width()` and `fill()`; handling
the base would be significantly more difficult.

Comment: i am just beginner, there's so much new things for me in your code. i have found the simplier solution in first answer. maybe your solution is better and faster, i don't know, but for know i think i am ok with that char c = someInt+'0';. anyway thanks very much, i will take a look on it when i will be experienced enough to understand it :)

Comment: @user1145902 My code uses the `someint + '0'` for the individual ints.  What it does in addition is address the issues of formatting; just a sequence of integers isn't (usually) very useful.

Comment: This answer also includes the boost library in a sneaky fashion. *hisses*

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `arr[]` is your int array. Then you can do:

```
int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); // get size of arr[]
char *intstr = new char[size+1]; // preallocate string 
intstr[size] = 0; // terminate string
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    intstr[i] = '0' + arr[i];
}
```

That's all. Only standards used...

Comment: Why do people insist on using things like `sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( arr[0] )`?  If you really need the size, `std::end( arr ) - std::begin( arr )` is preferable; even more idiomatic would be to rewrite the code to use the iterators returned by these functions.  The advantage is that they won't compile if `arr` is a pointer; the `sizeof` expression compiles, but gives wrong results.

Comment: @JamesKanze I just wanted to show that this is possible without the use of any std:: stuff. Of course there are more elegant ways to solve this, but they are also harder to "step through" by thought.