# C#, Bad characters when reading registry value

Tags: c#, wpf, registry

I use this code to read values from the registry:

```
appManufacturer = (string)subKey.GetValue("Publisher");
```

This is result:
[image]

The value in the registry looks like this:
[image]

When I looked at the string during debugging value was "Microsoft \0". Why? Where did "\0" comes from? What do i do wrong here?

Comment: Its always been there ... [Related: What does the \0 symbol mean in a C string?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4711449/1324033)

Comment: @Sayse While that explains what it is, it doesn't explain why it's there. If registries store the null-character, then one would expect the .NET library to handle that automatically. That being said, I've accessed registry entries via .NET and never encountered the null-char, so something seems fishy about this entry.

Comment: @Rob - I was more trying to just explain what it was rather than offer a solution

Answer (score -1):

The below code will allow you to get a registry value.

```
    string keyname = "SAVCE";
    Console.WriteLine(Read(keyname));    

    public static string Read(string KeyName)
    {
        using (RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Symantec\InstalledApps"))
        {
            return (string)registryKey.GetValue(KeyName);
        }

    }
```