# Unexpected behavior in C

Tags: c, string

This is the question I'm working on : http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursively-remove-adjacent-duplicates-given-string/

Here's my code in Java for one pass :

```
/*If a character isn't repeating, copy it to str[j].
 * Find start and end indices of repeating characters. Recursively  call again
*  And starting position now should be end+1. Pass j and starting    position  */
public class removeDuplicates {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{


    char[] str = {'c','c'};
    removeDups(str,0,0,0);
    System.out.println(str);

}

public static void removeDups(char[] str,int j, int start,int flag) 
{
    /*Check if start character is repeating or not. If yes , then loop till you find
     * another character. Pass that characters index(new start) into a recursive call*/

    if(start == str.length-1) 
    {
        if(flag!=1)
        {
            str[j] = str[start];
            j++;

        }
        if(j<=str.length-1) 
        {


            str[j] = '0';

        }

    }

    while(start<str.length-1 && str[start]!='0') 
    {

        if(str[start+1]!=str[start]) 
        {

            str[j] = str[start];

            start++;
            j++;
            if(start==str.length-1) {removeDups(str,j,start,flag);}
        }


        else 
        {
            char ref = str[start];

            while(str[start]==ref) 
            {

                if(start<str.length-1)
                {
                    start++;
                }
                else 
                {
                    flag =1;
                    break;

                }

            }

            removeDups(str,j,start,flag);
            return;

        }

    }




}
}
```

This works as expected. Here I'm just trying to use a 0 instead of  \0 character as in C. Now when I translate the code to C

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

 void removeDups(char *str,int j, int start,int flag) 
{
    /*Check if start character is repeating or not. If yes , then loop till you find
     * another character. Pass that characters index(new start) into a recursive call*/



    if(start == strlen(str)-1) 
    {
        if(flag!=1)
        {
            str[j] = str[start];
            j++;

        }
        if(j<=strlen(str)-1) 
        {


            str[j] = '\0';



        }

    }

    while(start<strlen(str)-1 && str[start]!='0') 
    {

        if(str[start+1]!=str[start]) 
        {

            str[j] = str[start];

            start++;
            j++;
            if(start==strlen(str)-1) {removeDups(str,j,start,flag);}
        }


        else 
        {
            char ref = str[start];

            while(str[start]==ref) 
            {

                if(start<strlen(str)-1)
                {
                    start++;
                }
                else 
                {
                    flag =1;
                    break;

                }

            }

            removeDups(str,j,start,flag);
            return;

        }

    }





}

int main() 
{


char str[] = "abcddcba";

int len =
while()

for(int i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++) 
{

    printf("%c",str[i]);
}
printf("\n");
}
```

The above code gives different results as compared to the Java code.Its virtually identical , just that I'm using strlen() instead of str.length(as in Java).

The interesting part is : if I change the portion to

```
if(j<=strlen(str)-1) 
        {


            str[j] = '\0';

            return;
}
```

it works perfectly. I've just added a **return** statement to the if statement.

Why is this happening ? Identical code producing different results in C and Java

Answer (score 1):

You are using `return` statement and subsequently all code below that `return` is being excluded from running for that iteration.

Also, You may want to understand what is `\0` is and how it's different than `0`.
Here's link:

[What does the \0 symbol mean in a C string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711449/what-does-the-0-symbol-mean-in-a-c-string)

Answer (score 0):

In C, assigning a character in a string to `'\0'` changes the length, so `strlen()` will return a different result after that.  In your Java code, you're using an array, and an array length never changes.  You're setting the character to `'0'` instead of `'\0'`, which are two different things, but even if you did set it to `'\0'`, it still wouldn't change the length.  I haven't examined your entire code, but this is one obvious thing that would cause different results.

Comment: Yes, that's the intended behavior.

Comment: You're saying the intent of the Java code was to change the length?  In that case, the Java code doesn't work.  `str.length` doesn't change just because you set an element to `'0'`.  As I said, however, I haven't studied your code thoroughly enough to see what works and what doesn't work.