# Strange behaviour when printing elements of String Arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays

I know it is a very simple code, but when printing the elements of the array the 4th element is printed twice like showed bellow.

```
void printWeekDays(){
char days[7][9] = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
for(int i=0; i < 7; i++){
    printf("%s \n",days[i]); 
}
```

Monday
 
Tuesday
 
WednesdayThursday
 
Thursday
 
Friday
 
Saturday
 
Sunday

Here is my environment:
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0

Comment: Compile with warnings enabled. `-Wall`

Comment: And the **correct fix** is to have **`static`** `const char *days[7] = { ...`

Comment: xing If I change the days[7][9] to days[7][10] it works, but why we have this strange behaviour? The C compilers seems to concatenate the 3th and 4th element.

Comment: @RodrigoCamargos `printf` will check for `\0` char to stop printing but your `thursday` does not have it.

Comment: @RodrigoCamargos strings are NULL terminated. But `Wednesday\0` requires 10 characters. Unfortunately no warning is generated by clang because you're squeezing it to fit in 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"Wednesday"` needs `char[10]` to hold the `\0` char.

You get strange behavior because `printf` will search for `\0` in the input string to stop printing but your `"wednesday"` does not have `\0` char appended.

Hence `printf` goes on printing until it gets `\0` that is after printing `"thursday"`.

Change this

```
char days[7][9]
```

to

```
char days[7][10]
```

or

```
const char *days[7] //Compiler automatically adjust the size needed to store string literals.
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks kiran.

Comment: Is there any difference between const char* and char* ? Why use "const"?

Answer (score 0):

This is because `"Wednesday"` doesn't fit in an array of 9 characters. Sure, there's just 9 letters in Wednesday, but with the null terminator that is put at the end of each string, that's 10 characters. What happens is that the null terinator goes where the `T` from `"Thursday"` goes, and when `"Thursday"` is written to its corresponding place, that null terminator is overwritten. Hence why both are printed after eachother when you try to print Wednesday. It doesn't stop at the end of Wednesday because the next null terminator is at the end of Thursday.

To fix it, change this:

```
char days[7][9] = {
```

To this:

```
char days[7][10] = {
```

If you don't know about how null terminators work and would like to learn more, you can read about it [here](http://www.cs.ecu.edu/karl/2530/spr17/Notes/C/String/nullterm.html).

Comment: My compiler didn't issue any warning, but I understood the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @RodrigoCamargos C compilers don't warn for this bug: it is a defect in the C language. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52385351/c-string-at-the-end-of-0