# Remove spaces from string not taking effect

Tags: c++, stdstring

I'm trying to remove all characters and spaces except letters. But the "erase spaces" part doesn't take effect, it will only take effect if I comment out the remove characters part.

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        if (!(s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z' || s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z'))
        {
            s[i] = '\0';
        }

    }

s.erase(remove(s.begin(), s.end(), ' '), s.end());
```

Comment: `\0` is null, not a space.

Comment: '\0' is not what u want, you can use '' or ' ' depending on what you want.
take a look at this for '\0': https://stackoverflow.com/a/4711475/4022530

Comment: @Majidkhalili Why is '\0' "not what u want"? Your link is about string literals & C strings, something completely different.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit as far as I understood he wants to remove the characters that are not letters, not replacing them with null or anything else, the link is just to say what '\0' is

Comment: @Majidkhalili It looks like you did not fully understand the program. First the OP replaces unwanted characters with a "sentinel" or "placeholder" value (and has chosen `\0` for this, apparently already understanding what that is, and understanding that `std::string` is null-safe). Then, they efficiently remove the placeholder characters using the erase-remove idiom. You claimed _"`\0` is not what u want"_ but there does not seem to be any basis for this claim. Aside from the typo (and I'm not sure about those `&&`/`||` offhand), the code in the question is fine.

Comment: I would use `remove_if` instead of `remove`. Then this can be accomplished in one step instead of two.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sure, u r right, my mistake

Answer (score 3):

You're replacing all the non-alphabetic characters with NULs, then removing all the spaces.  Since NULs are not spaces, this latter step does nothing.  If you change the assignment in the loop to

```
s[i] = ' ';
```

you would instead replace them with spaces, which would then be removed by the `eraser(remove`

If you want to make the code more readable, you could replace the complex if with

```
if (!isalpha(s[i]))
```

or you could even replace the whole thing with

```
s.erase(remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char ch){ return !isalpha(ch); });
```

Comment: But now your program is harder to debug, because there is no distinction between "a previously-valid character that I failed to replace for some reason" and "a character that I failed to remove for some reason". A `\0` is honestly a good choice; it just needs to be used consistently.

Comment: Spaces are easier to see in a debugger output than NULs, usually.  `'\0'` has the problem that it may be invisible if output.  IMO any printable character would be easier to debug than a NUL...

Comment: Any debugger that renders nulls as "invisible" should be shot. Have you encountered one that does?

Comment: Besides, you may be debugging by simply printing the numeric value of each character in the string, which will tell you immediately exactly what is going on in the event of a bug.

Comment: That's the case that is most difficult -- if you simply output the string (to cout) the NULs will be invisible.

Comment: Why would you emit the actual characters if you're debugging? You should emit their numeric values...

Comment: That's a lot more work than a simple `cout << s << flush;` added to the code.

Comment: It's absolutely trivial (`for (const auto ch : s) cerr << hex << +ch << ' '; cerr << '\n';`) and you should already have a function to do this (ideally one that also emits the printables alongside, [ala `hexdump`](https://gist.github.com/tomalakgeretkal/594da2d34c51c3642a6f844333ae9e52)) in your toolkit. Either way, you're arguing to do something in an ambiguous way because you have inadequate diagnostic tools, which is a backwards way to program.

Answer (score 1):

So you replaced the characters you don't want with `'\0'`.

Then you removed all `' '` characters.

That last stage presumably should involve `'\0'`…

Comment: Except wouldn't a null prematurely end the string, or is `std::string` smarter than that?

Comment: @Chipster `std::string` is perfectly null-safe.

Comment: @Chipster A `std::string` knows its size and can hold embedded nulls. It's *not* a C-style null terminated string.

Comment: A null is the most appropriate character to use here anyway, compared to some alternative like a space. Not only is it semantically reasonable, but it'll then be easier to distinguish "characters I forgot to replace" with "characters I forgot to remove" when you're debugging a problem.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit A null wouldn't be the best here if it terminated at null like a c string would, since it'd become impossible to know the actual length from just the pointer. You couldn't really remove NULL then. But, since you guys have cleared up that that is not the case, then yes, NULL is the best here. +1, btw.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of future readers: in C++20, we have unified erasure, so we can simply use

```
std::erase_if(s, [](unsigned char c) { return !std::isalpha(ch); });
```

(See [Do I need to cast to unsigned char before calling toupper(), tolower(), et al.?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21805674)
 for why `unsigned char` should be used)